# Is it good practice to define a model when using data from a plist file?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, plist

Should I read/write data directly from/to a plist file in the view controller or is it better to define a class for the model and then use its methods to read/write data?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you're doing. If you are doing extensive work with the `.plist` file, then it's probably better to write a class to handle all of the different things you're doing to it. If you're just taking one value out one time or something similar then you could write a class, but it's not really a significant issue.

You don't want your view controller to end up doing a lot of the lifting in areas that don't pertain directly to the view, so just think about how much code you'll be adding. If you think there's a chance you might want to do more things with the `.plist` file then go ahead and write a class for it.

Comment: @DustineRowland Thanks for the answer, appreciate it.